# POST data to CGI file using XMLHttpRequest causes BadHeader

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

When I try posting data to my CGI file, my CGI file says the actual post data is invalid. I am using HTML/JavaScript for the front end and Python for the backend.

Works:

```
<form name="login" action="/cgi-bin/register.py" method="POST">
Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
Confirm password:<input type="password" name="confirmpassword"><br>
</form>
```

However, this causes the page to refresh. I am trying to avoid this and have text display within the same page(without reloading). Hence, I have chosen to use an XMLHTTPRequest to asynchronously process this event.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
<script>
function validateLogin()
{
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if (username.length <= 0 || password.length <= 0)
  {
  document.alert("The username or password cannot be blank");
  return;
  }

var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }else if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            document.write(xmlhttp.status + xmlhttp.statusText);
        }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","/cgi-bin/login.cgi",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
}
</script>
```

CGI File:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
from dbmanager import openConnection
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

s = "Content-type: text/html\n\n\n"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

username = form["username"].value
password = form["password"].value
message = None
```

I am getting an error in python stating `Bad header=FieldStorage(None, None,`

I don't get this error when I do it the first way, but the second way is giving me this error. I **need** it to work the second way.

Answer (score 4):

For echo Server :

## HTML :

```
<html>
 <head>

 <script>
function validateLogin()
{
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if (username.length <= 0 || password.length <= 0)
  {
  document.alert("The username or password cannot be blank");
  return;
  }

var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }else if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            document.write(xmlhttp.status + xmlhttp.statusText);
        }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","../post_test.py",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
}
</script>
 </head>




 <body>


<form name="login" >
Username:<input type="text"  id="username"><br>
Password:<input type="text"  id="password"><br>
Confirm password:<input type="text"  id="repassword"><br>

</form>
<button onclick="validateLogin()">Login</button>
<span id="resultText"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

## CGI-SCRIPT:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import cgi


form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"
print
print form
```

Replace input type `password` to `text` because got security bugs !

Yo got wrong answer on cgi script. Who know service is live ? So need some type, status, header, content..

Check post address : `..//` mean `currient_uri + new_path + target`

On javascript: Call by ID but where ID parameter ?

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript doesn't post the right values because of wrong HTML elements properties.

Try changing the `name` property of elements `username` and `password` into `id` property as requested by your JavaScript code.

The result will be something like this:

`<form name="login" action="/cgi-bin/register.py" method="POST">
Username:<input type="text" id="username"><br>
Password:<input type="password" id="password"><br>
Confirm password:<input type="password" id="confirmpassword"><br>
</form>`