# Calling python script from javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I have the following html code (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


        <script>
        function addParagraphText()
        {
        var arg1=2
        var arg2=34
        var arg3="john"
        var myResult = runMe.py(arg1, arg2, arg3)
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = myResult
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="addParagraphText();">Click me</button>
<p id="para"></p>
</html>
```

and the following python file runMe.py:

```
import sys

myArg1 = sys.argv[1]
myArg2 = sys.argv[2]
myArg3 = sys.argv[3]
# some long calculations using various libraries and modules



myOutput = '''<table style=\"border:solid;\"><tr><td> bla </td><td> lol bla <button>myButton</button> </td></tr><tr><td> blabla </td><td> blablabla </td></tr></table>'''

return myOutput
```

Obviously it doesn't work. What would be the easiest and quickest way to do it? I have a very long Python script that does some calculations and outputs a rather long string in html format which I would like to present after user clicks on the button. As of now, I do not need a state of the art approach, I am rather looking for a fast and easy solution.

Comment: You can't run python scripts in the browser. What you can do, is run a server with your python script and make calls to it...

Answer (score 2):

In short: JavaScript in a html page executed by a browser cannot start the python interpreter and cannot run python scripts.

Browser security will prevent this.

You'll have to use something like XHR and cgi like in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355220/post-data-to-cgi-file-using-xmlhttprequest-causes-badheader). The first answer seems to be a complete example.
Otherwise [try wsgi python](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html).